# Commerce Server: Custom counters file view is out of memory

Tags: windows-server-2003, performancecounter, commerceserver2007

Commerce Server seems to be adding a ton of counters for each catalog/site, and we are currently pushing 45 of them. I tried upping the size in the machine.config which helps, but not enough.

Does anyone know how to programmatically clear out the commerce server counters? Barring that, disable them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a great deal of research, I ended up putting together this .reg file that would disable all the counters. Copy/paste this into a .reg file, run it, and reboot the server, and it will stop registering counters for commerce server

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Commerce: Catalog\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Commerce: Catalog Pipeline\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Commerce: Marketing\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Commerce: Orders\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Commerce: Pipelines\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Commerce: PromoCode Pipeline\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\csauthperf\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cscustomperf\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\csdwperf\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\csmarketingperf\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\csupmperf\Performance]
"Disable Performance Counters"=dword:00000001
```